# Submit one form receive different results

Tags: php, forms

in my shop I have a table with articles which is filled by mysql data.
To exact the same table I want to include a column "input type" field where I can manually add additional comments to each article.
This is how the code looks like at the submitting page:

```
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $values["item_article"]?></td>
        <td><form action="shopping_cart.php" method="POST"><input type="text" name="travel"></td>
        <td>€ <?php echo $values["item_price"];?></td>
    </tr>
                
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button button1">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

This is the code at the receiving page:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_article"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['travel']?></td>
    <td>€ <?php echo $values["item_price"];?></td>
</tr>
```

By submitting more than one article (and each article has a different comment in the input type field) I receive only one and the same comment as a result for all articles.

[example picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03SNP.png)

As you can see in the example picture I have no problems with receiving 3 different articles ($values). The only problem I have is that I receive one comment instead of tree different comments (one per article).

How can I receive for each article the desired/ different comment?

THANKS

Comment: Your image shows article `A B C` and comments `D9 D9 D9`, but the code you posted has `item_article`, `travel`, `start_date`, `item_price`... I think you are sharing the wrong code here

Comment: I have updated the image. The former one was showing the relevant area where I have problems. Hope the new image helps with finding the problem solution

Comment: In addition I have sipmlified the code

Comment: `$_POST` contains the values from the form `<input type="text" name="travel">`, specifically `$_POST['travel']`. Your other variable `$values` must be wrong / try changing it to  `$_POST["item_article"]`